# Play video from blob data Oracle using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle11g, blob

i have created simple project save blob file data into oracle database using c# winform and worked fine. Now, i wanna play video from blob oracle data using c# but i couldn't. here is my code:

```
if (koneksidb.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    koneksidb.con.Close();
}
koneksidb.con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataReader dr;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ID,FILENAME, FILEDATA, KETERANGAN, SUBSTR(FILENAME, -4)AS FILEEXTENTION FROM LATIHANFILEMANAGER WHERE ID = '1' AND ISPREVIEW = N'1'";
cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    string fileExtention = dr["FILEEXTENTION"].ToString(); //got file extention from database
    switch(fileExtention)
    {
        case ".pdf": //when blob is pdf file worked fine
            byte[] FileBytes = (byte[])dr["FILEDATA"];
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(FileBytes);
            fmPdfViewer f = new fmPdfViewer();
            f.pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(stream); //when file .pdf i can display preview using pdf viewer in devexpress
            f.Show();
            break;
        case ".mp4": //when blob is video
            string path = ""; //here the problem how can i play file video from blob oracle data
            fmVideoViewer vd = new fmVideoViewer();
            vd.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = path;
            vd.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = true;
            vd.Show();
            break;
    }
}
dr.Close();
```

really need the solution, thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the file on disk and play it.

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])dr["FILEDATA"];    
string name = (string)dr["FILENAME"] + (string)dr["FILEEXTENTION"];    
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, name);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path , bytes);
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = path;
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

You can use `Application.StartupPath` or any other path you prefer to cache files.

After a while it's better to cleanup cached files.

Comment: how can i cleanup cached files?

Comment: For example you can delete all cached files when the application is closing.